# jQuery: Delayed fade unless clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects, fade

So I currently I have this:

```
$('#message_notice').click(function(){
   $(this).fadeOut('slow'); 
});

$('#message_notice').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow');
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is if a message is clicked, then go ahead and fade it out. Otherwise, in X seconds, fade it out automatically.

I can do one or the other, but if I have both (as in my example) then the on-click doesn't work (just the delayed fade).

I'm using jQuery 1.4.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`.stop(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) in the click handler to cancel the `delay()` that you put in the queue.

New code should look like

```
$('#message_notice').click(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).fadeOut('slow'); 
});

$('#message_notice').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you run

```
$('#message_notice').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow');
```

you are creating an animation queue to which your

```
$('#message_notice').fadeOut('slow');
```

gets appended if someone clicks.

For a solution see the answer by SLaks who posted it faster than I could finish writing...